# HTACCESS: How to Add X-Robots-Tag to a Specific Directory?

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried to look for this answer here as well as Stackoverflow and could not find an applicable answer.

I'm trying to add X-Robots-Tag 'noindex' to a specific directory on my website via HTACCESS.

**Purpose:** I want to prevent all pages within this directory from being indexed by search engines.

**My Setup:** PHP version 5.6.40 / Apache / Linux

**Clarification:** This is not a physical directory. This is a virtual directory that exists via URL rewrite.

Example URL: http://www.example.com/newsletters/

Example URL: http://www.example.com/newsletters/spring.html

Comment: "could not find an applicable answer" - what was wrong with the answers you found? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Apache 2 I believe. I tried to use phpinfo() to find out, but it just gave me a general 'Apache' as version.

Comment: All of the answers I found were applicable to physical directories, not virtual directories that are created via url rewrites.

Comment: As to the version of Apache... it's really whether you are using version 2.2 or 2.4. Apache 2.4 is the current version, however, many shared hosts are still on Apache 2.2 (EOL Jan 2018). With Apache 2.4 you can use Apache Expressions to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in that directory with the following mod_headers directive:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
```

> **UPDATE#1:** If this was a 'virtual' directory, how would the approach differ?

In that case, use the `.htaccess` file in the document root and set an environment variable (eg. `NOINDEX`) when the required URL-path is requested and set the `X-Robots-Tag` conditionally based on whether the env var is set.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/virtualdirectory/ NOINDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" ENV=NOINDEX
```

`SetEnvIf` is part of [mod_setenvif](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html).

The `ENV=` argument to the `Header` directive allows you to set that header only if the stated env var is set.

> **UPDATE#2:** Apache 2 I believe.

If you are on Apache 2.4+ (as opposed to Apache 2.2) then you can use an [Apache expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) instead of having to set an environment variable. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/virtualdirectory/#">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</If>
```

Comment: like this?: `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</IfModule>`

Comment: No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Just exactly as I've written it in my answer.

Comment: If this was a 'virtual' directory, how would the approach differ?

Comment: I've updated my answer and included an Apache 2.4 (only) version that uses Apache expressions.